# Automate launching Safari from a iOS mobile app using appium

Tags: ios, mobile, automation, appium

I am doing some automation with *Appium* on a *iOS mobile app*.

I need to:

- open the app
- do some tasks
- open safari

I looked around how to do it but I've been reading that it's impossible due to a limitation in apple's framework, it doesn't allow you to sent commands to more than one app per session.

Does anyone know a way around this? Or if what I read is just not 100% true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't allow you to sent commands to more than one app per session

Thats true, but you can run **2 sessions** in a **single test**:

1. create instance of appium driver with **app**-based capabilities
2. do what you need in the app
3. quit driver
4. create instance of appium driver with **browser**-based capabilities
5. do what you need in the safari
6. quit driver

In a quick way it may look like:

```
@Test
public void testBothAppAndSafari() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL appiumServerUrl = new URL("<your appium server host>");
    DesiredCapabilities appCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // put required native app capabilities in appCaps
    DesiredCapabilities safariCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // put required safari capabilities in safariCaps

    IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(appiumServerUrl, appCaps);
    driver.findElement(<locator for element in native app>).click();
    // do whatever you want with mobile app
    driver.quit();

    driver = new IOSDriver(appiumServerUrl, safariCaps);
    driver.findElement(<locator for element in web>).click();
    // do whatever you want in safari
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see, it makes sense.. Can you give me an example of how to run 2 sessions in a single test? or redirect me to somewhere I can see how it is done? Thanks for the answer

Comment: I added example in java to the answer.

Comment: I'm almost making this work in **ruby**, just when I create the second driver Safari doesn't launch, it just quits. Do you have any idea why this would happen. In any case, thanks a lot the answer, it was a huge help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach,

1. Created two setup one for app and other for safari.
2. First launch application and perform task
3. clear first session
4. Created again new Appium object for safari ( call second setup )
5. Perform browser activity
6. Close safari appium session

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense but I don't really understand what you mean when you say `created two setup one for app and other for safari`. :P

Answer (score 0):

You also can follow my approach without quit driver.

1. Go terminate application. (I've used javascript to run [terminateApp](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-apps-management/#mobile-terminateapp) cause native method not work for me.)
2. Find Safari on Home screen and then click on it
3. Use drive.get to open website as you expected.
4. In there you can change to `WEBVIEW_***` to inspect web element.
5. Back to native context by `NATIVE_APP` keyword

**Sample code:**

```
    System.out.println("Run application");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("bundleId", "com.example");
    boolean terminalApp = (boolean) driver.executeScript("mobile: terminateApp", params);
    System.out.println("terminateApp: " + terminateApp);
    driver.findElementById("Safari").click();
    Set<String> contextNames = appDriver.getContextHandles();
    // Change context to WEBVIEW_***
    appDriver.context(String.valueOf(contextNames.toArray()[1]));
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.vn");
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    // Do something. 
    // ...
    // If you want to communicate with NATIVE context just change to NATIVE_APP.
    appDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can activate system apps via `driver.activateApp(BUNDLE_ID);`

there is no need to kill the app driver and start browser driver to access browser, just switch between apps.

safari

```
driver.activateApp("com.apple.mobilesafari");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved the issue:

```
driver2.activateApp("com.apple.mobilesafari");

Thread.sleep(5000);
boolean openSafariTab =
                    driver2.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"AddTabButton\"]")).size() > 0;
            if (openSafariTab) {
                driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"AddTabButton\"]")).click();
            } else { }

Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name=\"TabBarItemTitle\"]")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"CapsuleViewController" +
                    "\"]/XCUIElementTypeOther[3]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]")).sendKeys("https://www.golfbpm.com");

Thread.sleep(3000);
          
 driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"Go\"]")).click();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?